# I want in download XML file for parsing?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am using using following code to download the file form receptive source

```
  private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query  
    Log.v("Start Query", "Stream");
    conn.connect();
    Log.v("End Query", "Stream");
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();    
    Log.v(stream.toString(), "Stream");
    return stream;
}
```

I got following erros in log

11-09 12:39:59.386: D/SntpClient(73): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: i am using following url      http://thecybersoft.us/BridalExpo/Getmember.xml

Comment: does it work if you add the 'http://' protocol in the URL?

Comment: yes it works. You can open it. I have also download a sample code from http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

it has same error

Comment: I don't get it. Does your downloadUrl() method work when you put "http://" in the urlString param ?

Comment: Actually it has problem in opening connection in conn.connect();

Comment: can you simply send the code for downloading XML

Comment: Yes im using with http:// but it doesnot working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
      URL url = new URL(urlString);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
      conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

      Log.v("Start Query", "Stream");          
      conn.connect();
      Log.v("End Query", "Stream");
      //read the result from the server
      BufferedReader rdr  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder();

      while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null)
      {
          sbr.append(line + '\n');
      }

      Log.v(sbr.toString(), "Stream");
```

Comment: what is data type o sbr. if it's string there is no append method in this

Comment: 11-09 12:56:45.842: V/http://thecybersoft.us/BridalExpo/Getmember.xml(2355): argument 1111
11-09 12:56:45.842: W/dalvikvm(2355): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-09 12:56:45.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-09 12:56:45.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-09 12:56:45.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
11-09 12:56:45.850: E/AndroidRuntime(2355):  at

Comment: Can you simple post the code to download XML and save it in string

Comment: Ok sorry change the conn.setDoOutput(true); to conn.setDoInput(true);