# Download With In Android

Tags: java, android, download

I'm a beginner with android programming.

I'm having some problem with downloading a file with android

I used Httpost, Httpget and hhtpurlconnection
the two first aren't working at all 
and the the third can't download tow times

I want a way to download different xmls to string or inputstream (or something convertable to them) to parse those XMLs.
besides the method should be able to do something like this :

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedStr);
```

because the xmls are responses from an API

Comment: See this answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481027/i-want-in-download-xml-file-for-parsing

Comment: But in The Second Time I Use It, It Shows An Error And Exits

Comment: @EbrahimTahernejad Then read the error

Comment: The problem is here it shows the common android error dialog ... but it doesn't show the ploblem in the log :|

Answer (score 2):

Here I am putting an example how to download an image file from server. I am asuming that on your local server there is a picture folder and you are downloading pic from that..
Use following code it may help you..

```
public class DownloadType1  extends Activity{

    String dwnload_file_path = "http://10.0.2.2/pictures/webicon.PNG";
    String dest_file_path = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/pictures/img1.png";
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download1);
    }


     public void onClick(View v) {

         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadType1.this, "", "Downloading file...", true);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                      downloadFile(dwnload_file_path, dest_file_path);
                 }
               }).start();               
     }

     public void downloadFile(String url, String dest_file_path) {
         try {
             File dest_file = new File(dest_file_path);
             URL u = new URL(url);
             URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
             int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

             DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

             byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
             stream.readFully(buffer);
             stream.close();

             DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
             fos.write(buffer);
             fos.flush();
             fos.close();
             hideProgressIndicator();

         } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
             hideProgressIndicator();
             return; 
         } catch (IOException e) {
             hideProgressIndicator();
             return; 
         }
   }

   void hideProgressIndicator(){
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });  
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D This is not what I wanted but it is another part of my project :D

Answer (score 0):

Below an example that you can use to download a file. Naturally you will have to use a correct URL.

```
  public InputStream downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl(final String url) {

    log.info(String.format("downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl: %s", url));


    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient client;
    try {
      client =  new DefaultHttpClient();

      final HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
      final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        log.warn("Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
        return null;
      }

      final HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
      final InputStream content = getResponseEntity.getContent();
      return content;

    } catch (final IOException e) {
      getRequest.abort();
      log.warn("Exception in downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl, error for URL " + url + e, e);
    }
    finally {
      // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
      // shut down the connection manager to ensure
      // immediate deallocation of all system resources
      client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return null;

  }
```

Comment: True, forgot to remove it, I edited the code, it should be right now.